# Suppose$f:S_{3}\longrightarrow R^{\ast}$is Homomorphism.Then Kernal of h has

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> **Question** Suppose$f:S_{3}\longrightarrow R^{\ast}$is Homomorphism.Then
>   Kernal of h has

$\left(1\right)Always$ at most 2 elements

$\left(2\right)$$Always$ at most 3 elements

$\left(3\right)Always$ at least 3 elements

$\left(4\right)Always$ exactly 6 elements

**Book Mention Option (4) is correct**

**My Approach**My problem is first fundamental theorem of isomorphism.

Option $\left(4\right)Always$ exactly 6 elements$\Longrightarrow$Ker$\left(f\right)=S_{3}$

S$_{3}/ker\left(f\right)$= {Identity Element} It's order is 1

If Ker$\left(f\right)$=A$_{3}$

|S$_{3}$/ker$\left(f\right)$| =2

And order of R$^{*}$is infinite

**R$^{*}$ is is group of non-zero real number under usual multiplication**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ is abelian, kernel of the map should contain commutator subgp of $S_3$.

Comment: Maybe one should add that there is a homomorphism (e.g. sign) $S_3\rightarrow\mathbb R^*$ whose kernel has $3$ elements to show that option (4) is false?

Comment: Okk i got that Just give me 2 minutes

Comment: @awllower Yes. And we call that homomorphism as \emph{sgn}. Even permutations go to +1, odds go to -1.